# Livy REST Spark java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, livy

I am newer in BigData, i have tried to call spark jobs with apache Livy .
With submit command line works fine . with livy i have exception

- the command line :

  > curl -X POST --data '{"file": "/user/romain/spark-examples.jar", "className": "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8998/batches
- Livy logs :

`2019-06-01 00:43:19,160 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://localhost:9000/home/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.3.jar does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatusInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:795)
    .......org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)`

Comment: Does the jar that is mentioned in the error exist (and is it accessible at the specified location).

Comment: yes the jar exist and submit execute :  ./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.cores=2 examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.3.jar 100
2019-06-03 22:55:19,494 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Pi is roughly 3.1418867141886713

Comment: That command is using your local filesystem, not HDFS. Try `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/home/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.3.jar` to see the same exception

Comment: @cricket_007 the result is  No such file or directory

Comment: Right... So you need to do `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal` to copy from your local path into that HDFS path (and probably also `hadoop fs -mkdir /home` first)

Answer (score 0):

related to @cricket_007  comment resolved by execute hadoop fs -copyFromLocal command line

Answer (score 0):

If it is in local machine then try using `'file':'local:<path/to/file>`